# Refreshing UI after update to a ListBox-bound collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, observablecollection

I am trying to visually show that an item (a BitmapImage in my case) has been added to a collection in a ListBox using WPF/MVVM. To give some background, I'm capturing streaming video with a capture card, and I'm taking still images while the video is streaming. These images are captured by clicking the "Still Image" button on the UI. After capturing an image, I would like for a thumbnail of said image in a separate panel on the UI. I understand what needs to be done to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Right now, my Model does all the data retrieval.

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> GetAssetThumbnails()
{
    var imageDir = ImgPath != null ? new DirectoryInfo(ImgPath) : null;
    if(imageDir != null)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo imageFile in imageDir.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
            {
                var uri = new Uri(imageFile.FullName);
                _assetThumbnails.Add(new BitmapImage(uri));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return _assetThumbnails;
}
```

My ViewModel creates a new instance of the model in its constructor, and then sets the public property `AssetCollection` equal to `_assetModel.GetAssetThumbnails()`. The ViewModel has all the standard OnPropertyChanged events and event handling.

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

#region Public Properties
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> AssetCollection
{
    get { return _assetCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (_assetCollection != value)
        {
            _assetCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AssetCollection");    
        }
    }
}
#endregion

private void _assetCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("AssetCollection");
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Then, in my XAML file, I bind the ListBox's item source to AssetCollection.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBoxAssets" ItemsSource="{Binding AssetCollection}" Grid.Row="1" Background="{DynamicResource GrayColor}" Margin="5,0,0,5" ></ListBox>
```

I've read that each item in the collection should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I tried creating a wrapper class for a bitmap image that implemented that, but it didn't work either. Is there something that I'm missing here? The images show up initially, but don't refresh after an image has been captured and saved. I have a feeling it's stemming from the event `PropertyChanged` not getting called. I noticed through debugging that it is always null when it's checked, and thus the `OnPropetyChanged` method is never called. I'm not sure where I should add this event handler though. I only use the code-behind file to add the data context of the view model to the view, and that's it. That is where I would normally think to add any event handling. Can anyone see something simple that I am missing here?

Comment: Try "I tried creating a wrapper class for a bitmap image that implemented that, but it didn't work either." Again.  Changes to an item need to come from the item via NotifyPropertyChanged.  Did you use a public property?

Comment: Yes, the property is public. I'll try creating a wrapper class again. I might have missed something last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you changing the `ObservableCollection` when you update the list, or are you changing the items stored inside the collection?

If you're changing the items inside the collection, you need to find a way to tell WPF that the collection has changed when the individual items change so it knows to redraw it.

Usually the items in the collection implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so it's easy to attach a `PropertyChange` notification to the items in the list which tells WPF to raise the `CollectionChanged` event whenever a property changes.

```
// Wireup CollectionChanged in Constructor
public MyViewModel()
{
    ListOfSomeItems = new List<SomeItem>();
    AssetCollection.CollectionChanged += AssetCollection_CollectionChanged;
}

// In CollectionChanged event, wire up PropertyChanged event on items
void AssetCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Asset item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += Asset_PropertyChanged;
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Asset item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= Asset_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

// In PropertyChanged, raise CollectionChanged event
void Asset_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged("AssetCollection");
}
```

If the items don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you'll have to manually raise the `CollectionChanged` event anytime an item in the collection changes.

```
AssetCollection[0].Thumbnail = new BitmapImage(uri);
OnPropertyChanged("AssetCollection");
```

If you are changing the `ObservableCollection` itself by adding/removing items and are not seeing the UI update, then it sounds like it might be a syntax error somewhere we can't see.

The most common one I see is making changes to the private property and not the public property.

```
// Will not raise the CollectionChanged notification
_assetCollection = _assetModel.GetAssetThumbnails();

// Will raise the CollectionChanged notification
AssetCollection = _assetModel.GetAssetThumbnails();
```

Although I also see a lot of people who use a `List` or custom collection instead of an `ObservableCollection` as well, which does not raise the `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Well, when I capture a new image, it's just saved in the same directory that the images in the ObservableCollection are saved in. So I think I would need to be changing the items _inside_ the collection, and not the collection itself. Your examples were quite helpful, thanks! I'll try to make some changes that you listed and see if they work.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as this helped me understand what I was doing wrong in my code. I still haven't been able to update the UI properly, but that's beyond the scope of this question as it has to do with the event not being raised after a thumbnail is created.