# Bound data in WPF not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an application which shows some ListBox's. These ListBox's are bound to data. One of the lists is a list of Doors, while the other list is a list of Users.

The list of Doors are coming from a DataManager class which communicates with the database. The list of Users is coming from an other class which does some calculations.

I've bound the two ListBox's to their appropiate ObservableList getter setter.

For the door:

```
public ObservableList<Door> Doors
{
    get { return DataManager.Doors; }
}
```

and for the user:

```
public ObservableList<User> Users
{
    get { return classLogic._users; }
}
```

Here comes the  problem. When I add or remove a Door, the list on the UI gets updated. When I add or remove a User, the list doesn't get updated. I have to reload the view (restart the application) to update it. What am I missing? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out myself that there are three steps to complete. I don't believe a PropertyChanged event is needed to update the ListBox. This may be since .NET 4.0 because I've read in versions below, the databinding isn't really correct yet.

The first step is that the list has to be a `private static ObservableList<...>`. The second is that the getter of this list has to be the appropiate type as well. This means in my case, the following code needs to be in ClassLogic:

```
private static readonly ObservableList<User> _users= new ObservableList<User>();

public static ObservableList<User> Users
{
    get { return _users; }
}
```

And the third thing is, when calling this function (getter) in the DataContext class to bind the data to the ListBox, the classname has to be used instead of an instance of that class!

So, in this case it would be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the Users that are managed by the ClassLogic class
/// </summary>
public ObservableList<User> Users
{
    get { return ClassLogic.Users; }
    //wrong would be:
    //get { return classLogic.Users }
}
```

These 3 steps bound my data and made sure the ListBox updated when the contents of the list was updated as well.

Comment: nice , i wonder in what situation is the PropertyChanged event needed 
on a Collection Property i recall situations where it was needed .

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Perhaps when the List isn't Observable from start? I think of external applications or updating something which isn't a list but, for example, an image...

Comment: There is a difference between changing the ObservableCollection when you update the list and changing the items stored inside the collection. If items inside the collection are changed, INotifyPropertyChanged can be used.
From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469056/refreshing-ui-after-update-to-a-listbox-bound-collection

Answer (score 2):

an observable collection raises PropertyChanged for properties of each item
like if you had a IsDoorClosed Property it would update

removing an element raises a CollectionChanged event on Doors but the UI is not updated since 
a PropertyChanged event was not Raised on the Bound Property Doors .

you need to Raise A PropertyChanged event on Doors on each CollectionChanged of Doors .

something along the lines of : this is psado code , it was written here for as an example 
for your benefit  , so check for any syntax errors .

```
 Doors.CollectionChanged += OnDoorsCollectionChanged; 


 private static void OnDoorsCollectionChanged(object sender , CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      PropertyChanged(sender,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Doors"));
 }
```

Comment: Ok , i added an example , i don't know where your collection is located , but you need to raise PropertyChanged in your DataContext on  
"Doors" property .

also note that i wrote it here and not in VS , so take Syntax errors 
into account .

Comment: Well but the fun part is, I didn't do this on the User class. Still, the ListBox of User gets updated. How is this possible?

Comment: could you post the CS 
of 
classLogic._users  

and 

DataManager.Doors  
to compare , i think i have a general idea why this happens

Comment: CS? What do you mean with that? I just use the lists.Add() methods... Please note that Doors work, but Users don't. You have it the other way round :)

Comment: o'k 
my mistake , either way i would like to see how the collections 
are defined .

Comment: In `DataManger`, I have: `private static readonly ObservableList<Door> _doors = new ObservableList<Door>();`. In the `classLogic`, I have: `public ObservableList<User> _users = new ObservableList<User>();`

Comment: does User implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: No, and neither did the Door. But I figured out how to bind the data correctly after trying and failing for the past 3 hours. I'll update my answer tomorrow because I got to go now (I usually fix things right before I have to leave......). Thank you anyway for the time and explanation you took in! Have my upvote <3

Comment: Hey, check out my answer! Perhaps it's of some use to you as well.